# iOS uiwebview clear touch event history

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am disabling setUserInteraction for a uiwebview. After 5 seconds I enable it again. Problem is that if user touches it during this period of 5s, not execute an action but after this timeout, action is executed! How to disable userInteraction completely or clear event history before setting its interaction again? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```

and

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```

instead.

Though this disables user interaction for whole application so it might not be the right workaround for you.

Comment: could be useful but does the same! I have a jquery mobile page on a webview and seems that user webview touch keeps active

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Hope you get some better answers.

Comment: setInteractionEnabled and beginIgnoringInteractionEvents does the same, no actions while activated but after that, click action is done. Thanks for help